# what is the meaning of module name in imp.load_source?

Tags: python

There is a file named stock.py in d:\stock.py,i can load it as

```
import imp
x=imp.load_source('module_name','d:\\stock.py')
x
<module 'module_name' from 'd:/stock.py'>

it can be written as :
y=imp.load_source('module','d:\\stock.py')
y
<module 'module' from 'd:/stock.py'>
```

Any string can be used in arg of  imp.load_source(arg,'d:\stock.py'),what is the meaning of it then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any string can be used in arg of imp.load_source(arg,'d:\stock.py'),what is the meaning of it then?

Using a sensible value makes errors and debugging easier to understand. Also, you could trigger `__main__` blocks.